# Using private repo for ServiceStack X or web global tool

Tags: servicestack

Is there a way to use private repo for custom .NET core templates and use them with X and web global tools provided by ServiceStack?

Comment: FYI the `x` dotnet tool now supports creating templates from private repos, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

This has [now been implemented](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/x-tool-custom-template/8296/7?u=mythz) with [x dotnet tool](https://docs.servicestack.net/dotnet-tool):

```
$ dotnet tool install --global x
```

Where you can now create templates from any repo by specifying `user/repo` as the template name and to be able to access a private repo you'll need to either specify your GitHub Access Token with the `-token` argument, e.g:

```
$ x new user/repo TheProject -token {GITHUB_TOKEN}
```

Alternatively you can leave specifying the `-token` if you have your GitHub AccessToken in your `GITHUB_TOKEN` Environment variable.

The latest version also lets you install directly from a URL archive, e.g:

```
$ x new https://github.com/{user}/{repo}/archive/master.zip TheProject
```

Which you can use to install any previous release version.

The ServiceStack Docs contains info on [how ServiceStack's Project Template System works](https://docs.servicestack.net/web-new#how-it-works) where you can [change the GitHub Organization used to source its templates](https://docs.servicestack.net/web-new#available-project-templates) with the `APP_SOURCE_TEMPLATES` environment variable, e.g:

```
APP_SOURCE_TEMPLATES=NetCoreTemplates .NET Core C# Templates;
```

Comment: I did use the APP_SOURCE_TEMPLATES env variable to point to my org. It only pulls public repos from the org. Is there a way to pull private repos?

Comment: @vmtx There's no explicit support for private repos but setting `GITHUB_GIST_TOKEN` Environment Variable with a personal GitHub access token with the necessary read permissions might work.

Comment: i tried but did not work. Is the token only used for gist access? Looking at the source for the web tool, it looks like the token is used only on the publish command to publish app to Gist.